Filtering Entries by Taxonomy
have a "courses" collection that contains two taxonomies: "courses_levels" and "courses_categories". Currently, I use the following loop to iterate over all courses by level. However, I would now like to apply a filter based on the second taxonomy "courses_categories".
{{ taxonomy:courses_levels }}
    {{ entries query_scope="filter_by_categories_and_levels" }}
        {{ partial:courses.preview }}
    {{ /entries }}
{{ /taxonomy:courses_levels }}


Honestly, I have no idea how to do this. I was thinking of using a query_scope, provided I could retrieve the URL parameters. I have already set up a form that generates a URL that looks like this: http://url.test/formations/niveaux-et-categories?animalieres=1&artisanat=1.
How can I filter the entries using the second taxonomy?
Note: I am not looking for a JavaScript solution at this stage. I am working on my fallback solution without JS.
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Statamic\Query\Scopes\Scope;

class FilterByCategoriesAndLevels extends Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope.
     *
     * @param \Statamic\Query\Builder $query
     * @param array $values
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply($query, $values)
    {
       // HELP NEEDED HERE
    }
}


Statamic comes with a query builder, which you can utilize for this.
Now I do recommend you cache the result, cause (for our use-case at least, not sure how much content you have) it was quite slow.
For this, you would need to get all entries from X collection, and then filter on the appropriate taxonomy.
We have one setup for products, which looks as follows. (Keep in mind we have a lot of enums and stuff setup)
return Cache::remember(
    "products:{$contentType->value}:{$locale->value}",
    config('custom.caching.ttl'),
    function () use ($contentType, $locale) {
        /** @var EntryQueryBuilder $qb */
        $qb = EntryFacade::query();

        $qb
            ->where('collection', Collection::PRODUCTS->value)
            ->where('published', true)
            ->where('status', 'published')
            ->where('locale', $locale->value);

        if ($contentType === 'somevalue') {
            $qb
                ->whereJsonContains('tags', 'tags::sale')
                ->orWhereJsonContains('tags', 'tags::reduced');
        } else {
            $qb
                ->whereJsonDoesntContain('tags', 'tags::sale')
                ->whereJsonDoesntContain('tags', 'tags::reduced');
        }

        return $qb->get()->sortBy('order');
    }
);

If we apply that to your setup, it could look something like below. Where you use a whereJsonContains to check if something is present in the JSON, of course below will not be a working example of how to fix your problem, but it should be a nudge in the right direction.
Of course, dd'ing to see what data you are working with will be a great help to solve this problem :)
$qb = EntryFacade::query();

$qb
    ->where('collection', 'courses')
    ->where('published', true)
    ->where('status', 'published')
    ->where('locale', $locale->value)
    ->whereJsonContains('courses_categories', 'courses_categories::category_name');


Create a single query scope for both levels and categories may not be a good idea. Also, global scopes, like that FilterByCategoriesAndLevels class that you proposed, do not accept parameters.
I would create two local scopes in the Course class for each of those relationships.
class Course extends Model
{
    public function level()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Level::class);
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Level::class);
    }

    public function scopeAtLevel($query, $levelId)
    {
        return $query->whereRelation('level', 'id', $levelId);
    }

    public function scopeHavingCategory($query, $categoryId)
    {
        return $query->whereRelation('categories', 'id', $categoryId);
    }
}

Then you can retrieve the results by doing:
Course::atLevel(request('level_id'))
    ->havingCategory(request('category_id'))
    ->get();

I hope I understand you correctly. Pls clarify if it is not.

Thank you very much @Kevin Bui for your answer. However, is this compatible with the Statamic CMS environment ? It seems to me that the example provided here is a Laravel solution, isn't it?

I am sorry, I don't read the question carefully. So this is a statamic context. My answer doesn't help much then.
